# Wordpress & PHP Integration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have currently taken on board a wordpress website.  There is a PHP web app that I want to make, a login and download mp3 section that is not neccessarily open to the public.

Anyway we have paid for a theme and instead of writing a bunch of pages that don't look anything like the theme, I'd like it to look like the rest of the site.  But i cannot see how to add PHP into anything on this thing.  I have heard talk of page.php but I don't want the code to affect all pages.  How can I go about this?

Comment: This is quite a broad question being asked, you'll probably have better answers on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where you've bought the theme, it's likely you can ask for some programming service exending the theme to your programming needs. Normally the Wordpress login is re-used and for the downloading you can put them behind a wall, too. See [How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/37144/178).

Comment: Why don't you try first? Then when you encounter a _specific_ problem come back and post a question with your code and what you've tried so far and people might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either of the following:

1. Write a custom wordpress plugin (not hard, I've written dosens).  Then place that plugin on a wordpress page in the dashboard (not a post).  You can use a content filter to trigger the plugin.  It will then execute in the context of a page that is already rendered by the theme.
2. Create a custom page type.  You do this by physically copying and editing and then modifying one of the theme files.  Then you create a new wordpress page in the dashboard (again, not a post).  When formatting the page within wordpress, you choose the kind of page.  That is where you choose your new customised version of the theme page template.

For option 1, you are going to have to read the code of example plugins, and study the documentation on [the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page).  For option 2, there are probably some tutorials online.  Google should help you there.